# Binary focal loss in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I am trying to implement this:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02002.pdf eq4.
Many public available implementations are multi-class while my problem is binary.

I have tried

```
loss =  -((1-p) ** gamma) * torch.log (p) * target
```

where `p` is my sigmoid output , `target` my binary label and `gamma` a tuning parameter.
as it seems in the original paper.
Howver this does not penalize cases where `target == 0` and `p` is large, which I suspect has to do with multi-class original formulation.
I have then tried

```
loss =  ((1-p) ** gamma) * torch.log (p) * target +  (p) ** gamma * torch.log (1-p) * (1-target)
```

However, the loss just stalls on a dataset where BCELoss was so far performing well.

What's a simple correct implementation of focal loss in binary case?

Comment: Could you simply formulate as a multiclass n-class problem where n = 2?

Comment: Indeed. Is the above the correct semplification?the paper does not show the exact summation taking place

Comment: Your use of `p` = sigmoid output in the first expression is incorrect. In the original paper `p_r` is defined conditionally based on the true label, such that `p_r` = log(1-p) if y = 1 and log(p) if y = 0. (Essentially abs(y-p) but differentiable, as abs is not always differentiable). Modify your expression thusly and see if that changes your result. Thed original paper formulation should still work in the binary case